# Django form sporadic validation

Tags: python, django, forms, validation

I have a form accessed from a class-based generic UpdateView. It validates, among other things, that the event being updated is not on the same date as another.

The trouble is, when updating some fields, e.g. location, the changes are processed without an error being raised, but updating others, e.g. name, throws up validation errors about the event date clashing with another event, errors which should also occur when the location is edited.

Why does editing some fields raise validation errors and not editing other fields? Really the validation should check them all.

My view:

```
class EventEditView(UpdateView):
    template_name = "edit_event.html"
    pk_url_kwarg='event_id'
    model = Event
    form_class = EventEditForm
```

which uses this form:

```
class EventEditForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Event

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
        super(EventEditForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


    name = forms.CharField(max_length=1024,
        initial="Give short, descriptive name")
    location = forms.CharField(max_length=1024,
        initial="Be specific, give online map link")
    dateTimeOptions = {
        'format': 'dd/mm/yyyy HH:ii P',
        'autoclose': 'true',
        'showMeridian': 'true',
        }
    date = forms.DateTimeField(label="Date and time",
        widget=DateTimeWidget(options=dateTimeOptions,
        attrs={'id':"date-time"}))
    host_act = forms.CharField(max_length=1024,
        initial="What act will you bring, if any?", required=False)
    description = forms.CharField(required=False, max_length=10240)

    def clean_location(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        location = cd.get('location')
        if location == "Be specific, give online map link" or '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a location")
        return location

    def clean_name(self):
        cd = self.cleaned_data
        name = cd.get('name')
        other_names = Event.objects.proposed(datetime.now)
        if name == "Give short, descriptive name" or '':
            raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a name")
        return name

    def clean(self):
        """
        Check that there is not another event on at
        the same time and place. Then check that user has not committed
        to another event on the same date, even somewhere else.
        """
        cleaned_data = super(EventEditForm, self).clean()
        event_start_estimate = cleaned_data.get("date") - timedelta(hours=3)
        event_end_estimate = event_start_estimate + timedelta(hours=7)
        location = cleaned_data.get("location")
        events_on_date = Event.objects.\
            filter(date__range=[event_start_estimate,event_end_estimate])
        events_at_location_on_date = events_on_date.filter(location=location)
        # Check event clash is not this event clashing with itself
        #        events_with_same_date_and_location_id = events_at_location_on_date.values()[0]['id']
        #        this_event_id = self.instance.id
        try:
            if events_with_same_date_and_location_id == this_event_id:
                events_at_location_on_date = False
        except:
            pass
        if events_at_location_on_date:
            raise forms.ValidationError("There is already an event on \
                this date.")
        user = self.request
        print user
        events_on_date_user_has_commit = events_on_date.filter(host__exact=user)
        if events_on_date_user_has_commit:
            raise forms.ValidationError("You are already committed to an event\
                on this date.")
        return cleaned_data
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a few errors in your code which may or may not be related to your problem.

Your if statement in `clean_location` will always be false because `''` is false. I think what you want is this:

```
if name in ["Give short, descriptive name", '']:
```

Secondly, the same thing in `clean_name`. Should be:

```
if name in ["Give short, descriptive name", '']:
```

Third, in `clean`, you are using `self.request` as a user object:

```
user = self.request
```

Should be:

```
user = self.request.user
```

Maybe these changes will fix your problem.